# py2exe + sqlalchemy + sqlite problem

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, py2exe

I am playing around with getting some basic stuff to work in Python before i go into full speed dev mode. Here are the specifics:

```
Python 2.5.4
PyQt4 4.4.3
SqlAlchemy 0.5.2
py2exe 0.6.9
setuptools 0.6c9
pysqlite 2.5.1
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=[{"script" : "main.py"}], options={"py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip", "PyQt4.QtSql","sqlite3"],"packages":["sqlite3",]}})
```

py2exe appears to generate the .exe file correctly, but when i execute dist/main.exe i get this in the main.exe.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 14, in main
  File "db\manager.pyc", line 12, in __init__
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.pyc", line 223, in create_engine
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.pyc", line 48, in create
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\url.pyc", line 91, in get_dialect
ImportError: No module named sqlite
```

I've been googling my heart out, but can't seem to find any solutions to this. If i can't get this to work now, my hopes of using Python for this project will be dashed and i will start over using Ruby... (not that there is anything wrong with Ruby, i just wanted to use this project as a good way to teach myself Python)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you need to include the sqlalchemy.databases.sqlite package

```
setup(
  windows=[{"script" : "main.py"}],
  options={"py2exe" : {
    "includes": ["sip", "PyQt4.QtSql"],
    "packages": ["sqlalchemy.databases.sqlite"]
}})
```

Comment: I would give you +100 if i could :) Thanks

Comment: For those arriving at this question years later: sqlalchemy no longer has a package with this name; instead, it seems to be `sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite`.

Comment: In addiction to @Brandon's tip, for those using Firebird I found this option working: `"packages": ["sqlalchemy.dialects.firebird", "kinterbasdb"]`

Comment: For those using MySQL, you need to have `"ascii": 0` and `"packages": ["sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql","MySQLdb"]` in your py2exe dictionary. For python2.7 and sqlalchemy .7

Answer (score 5):

you need change to sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite package

setup(
  windows=[{"script" : "main.py"}],
  options={"py2exe" : {
    "includes": ["sip", "PyQt4.QtSql"],
    "packages": ["sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite"]
}})